# Are there Miners (or Mining Pools) that accept below standard fee transactions?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

Let's say I create a transaction of 0.0005 BTC with a fee of 0.000005 BTC. From looking at the bitcoin source I find that this transaction would be considered non-standard and therefore not accepted and relayed by any node running the satoshi bitcoind.

Are there any Miners or Mining Pools where I could directly relay this transaction, which would accept it and place it into a block? Would the resulting block be considered standard and accepted in the block chain by other nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a Bitcoin.it wiki site dedicated to this topic: [Free transaction relay policy](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Free_transaction_relay_policy)

Currently the only mining pool is eligius that accepts below standard fee transactions. Hopefully there is more to come :)